# EF linq statement not generating nested select count(*)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, linq-to-sql

We have a table of items which can have a number of images attached to them. I want to create an endpoint which returns all the items and also the number of images attached to each item as json.

I do this with the following linq statement:

```
var items = context.Items.AsNoTracking ();
return Json (await items.Select (item => new {
    item = item,
    numImages = item.Images.Count (),
}).ToListAsync ());
```

This works, but it's incredibly slow, because EF generates a separate SQL statement for each item like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Images` AS `q0` WHERE @_outer_IdImages = `q0`.`idImages`
```

How can I construct my linq so that only one query will be generated, like this:

```
SELECT idItems, name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Images WHERE idItems = i.idItems) FROM Items i;
```

Comment: Use a raw SQL query? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql

Comment: Which EF version?

Comment: Have you tried `.Include(item => item.Images)` prior to the `.Select()`?

Comment: @GertArnold Entity Framework Core 2.2.6-servicing-10079

Comment: @strickt01 There can be thousands of Images per Item, I do not want to include those with the result

Comment: With EF core 2 you have to settle with work-arounds. The issues with query translations are overwhelming. What I've seen in EF 3 it's become a lot better. A work-around could be to select *properties* of the items, instead of the items themselves.

Comment: @GertArnold It's too bad because there are a lot of properties in the items and I would rather not explicitly reference them in the code. I would have expected EF to generate sub-queries rather than separate DbCommands.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked around the performance problem by generating a dictionary of Image 
idItems to Counts, as below:

```
var items = context.Items.AsNoTracking ();
var imagesDict = await context.Images.AsNoTracking ()
    .GroupBy (img => img.IdItems)
    .ToDictionaryAsync (g => g.Key, g => g.Count ());
return Json (await items.Select (item => new {
        item = item,
        numImages = imagesDict.GetValueOrDefault (item.IdItems, 0),
    }).ToListAsync ());
```

It's not at all what I wanted, but it ends up being much faster because only two DbCommands are run. And it's a lot cleaner than raw SQL

Comment: I was starting to propose a solution like this. Probably the best you can do to avoid typing all `Item`'s properties in a a LINQ or raw SQL query.